# Using Function Source in Condition Sentence for DW

Tags: templating

I'm trying to make it work to use function source(Custom Function) in condition sentence for DW Template.

The Result is,

In case of adding @@　to the function source in front and behind,
the function source seems to work successfly( return the expected value)
but the condition sentence in DW Template is not resolved.  See here:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="@@CountFieldValues("Embeddable_Image_Link_Items")@@ > 1" -->
<!-- Banner Area -->
<div class="m-banner-box">
  <ul class="m-hover">
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Embeddable_Image_Link_Items" --><!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Image != ''" --><li><a href="@@Target_Link@@"  @@GetKeywordMetadataValue("Link_Type","${Link_Type}","Attribute")@@ ><img alt="@@Alt@@" height="" src="@@Image@@" width="" /></a></li><!-- TemplateEndIf --><!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /Banner Area --><!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

[image]

On the other hand, In case of not adding @@ to the function source in front and behind,
the function source itself seems not to be resolved:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="CountFieldValues("Embeddable_Image_Link_Items") > 1" -->
<!-- Banner Area -->
<div class="m-banner-box">
  <ul class="m-hover">
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Embeddable_Image_Link_Items" --><!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Image != ''" --><li><a href="@@Target_Link@@"  @@GetKeywordMetadataValue("Link_Type","${Link_Type}","Attribute")@@ ><img alt="@@Alt@@" height="" src="@@Image@@" width="" /></a></li><!-- TemplateEndIf --><!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /Banner Area --><!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

[image]

could you give me any ideas for this?

My function source is as follows:

```
    [TemplateCallable]
    public int CountFieldValues(string fieldName)
    {
        Component component = _engine.PublishingContext.ResolvedItem.Item as Component;

        int repeatCount = 0;

        if (component != null)
        {
            repeatCount = CountFieldValues(component, fieldName);
        }

        return repeatCount;
    }

    private int CountFieldValues(Component component, string fieldName)
    {
        int repeatCount = 0;

        XmlElement componentXml = component.Content;

        XmlNodeList componentChildXml = componentXml.ChildNodes;

        if (componentChildXml != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < componentChildXml.Count; i++)
            {
                if (componentChildXml.Item(i).Name == fieldName)
                {
                    repeatCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        return repeatCount;
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind Regards,

Naoki

Comment: Is this user CMS Info from TridionWorld? +1 to the question which includes background, problem, and code (as always). :-) I learn as much from your questions as I do from the answers.

Comment: I have answered with my own tests, but I saw that in your examples the problem could be the quotes in the expression, could you try simple quotes inside the function call

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="@@parseInt(${CountFieldValues("Embeddable_Image_Link_Items")})@@ > 1" -->
```

Mark Saunders' post here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dwt-strings-integers-and-repeatable-fields explains this in detail.  If on 2011 SP1 HR1, you may also want to give this hotfix a try: CM_2011.1.1.81739

Comment: Hi! Nickoli.
Thank you very much for your answer.

I tried the code you mention above.

but it still output the following code in the template builder.
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="2 > 0" -->

I also tried this
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="@@parseInt("2") > 0" -->

But this also result in the folloing same result
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="2 > 0" -->

do you have amy ideas for this issue?

Comment: you need to put @@ after parseInt as well:  @@parseInt("2")@@

Comment: I'm sorry this is just misstyping. I executed using @@parseInt("2")@@. But this also result in the folloing same result <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="2 > 0" -->
I thought none installation is needed before implementing above code.

Comment: Try restarting the server.  If restarting doesn't solve the issue, then log a ticket with support.

Comment: Hi! Nickoli. I tried but nothing changed. I'll contact to support. Thank you very much for taking your time.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the Dreamweaver Optional condition with an integer function source, and I didn't have any problem.
I have this code in a DW Page Template:

```
<p>cp: @@fcs_TotalNumberOfComponentPresentations()@@</p>
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="fcs_TotalNumberOfComponentPresentations() > 1" -->
<p>greater than 1</p>
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

It is a function with an integer result of the number of component presentations in a Page as:

```
[TemplateCallable]
public int fcs_TotalNumberOfComponentPresentations()
{
    int count = fcs_GetComponentPresentationsCount();
    return count;
}
```

And the results are ok:

With one component presentation
[image: template builder result with one cp]

And with two component presentations
[image: template builder result with two cp]

Maybe the problem is in the Content Manager versions of the dll's.
Check the "Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.dll" version in **TRIDION_HOME/bin/client**
 I have 6.1.0.996

Comment: Hi! Raúl.
Thank you  for your advice. I have also 6.1.0.996. btw is there any restriction that you have to use condition sentence within repeat sentence?